# Continuous Delivery with Fastlane

Tags: mobile, react-native, fastlane, continuous-delivery

I have recently moved from a web context into a mobile context (building a React Native app). One of the most powerful processes in the web world was Continuous Delivery. I would like to recreate a continuous delivery pipeline, into production, for the React Native mobile context. My understanding is that this is possible so long as only the javascript bundle gets updates rather than the underlying native components.

I have been finding blogs such as:
https://hiddentao.com/archives/2017/02/17/continuous-integration-for-react-native-with-testfairy-testflight-deploy/ and it appears that fastlane is the most common solution for Continuous Integration in the mobile ecosystem, but posts about Continuous Delivery are a little thin on the ground.

Is this because it is impossible? Is the promised land of "just update the js bundle" a lie? And if it is not impossible, how would I configure fastlane to push directly to production? Or would I use some other tool? Is it generally considered an anti pattern in the space? If so why?

Answer (score 1):

It **IS** possible to update the javascript portion of a React Native app.

Fastlane is a great tool for building and deploying mobile apps but it is not itself a continuous delivery tool. However, used in conjunction with some other CI tool (Jenkins etc) it can make it easy to configure app store or beta releases triggered at some set interval or based on a certain trigger.

Fastlane is primarily designed to solve the issues associated with building and deploying native applications and as such it is very useful for building/deploying the native RN app to the app store but is likely not the best tool for managing your JS pushes. There are a few tools that are popular for pushing the JS code:

https://deploy.apphub.io/

and

http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/

are two popular mechanisms specifically built for this purpose and provide command line tools for deploying updated javascript. These could be configured in Jenkins (or another CI server) without necessarily needing to use fastlane.

Answer (score 0):

As **@john_ryan** specified you could use [CodePush](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) for application updates. Nevertheless, it is worth taking into account some features of this solution:

1. You can't use hot updates if you need to add some native modules.
2. It strictly not recommended to use hot updates if you updated React Native version. In most cases, the consequences will be sad.
3. New users will get outdated built-in version at first app launching. Actual version will be presented on second run only.

Given all of the above CodePush is best for:

1. To decrease app update time for critical bugs.  Of course you must release native update as soon as possible in this case also.
2. Non major updates. For major updates in most cases you need to update screenshots, app description, release notes and draw the user's attention about update. Hot update for major changes does not fit because of "second run update" cycle.
3. Testing stability of new update on a small part of users.
4. A/B testing.

You should use **fastlane** in any case. It really cool for custom builds, updating stores meta info, screenshots etc. For beta builds delivery I recommend [Crashlytics Beta](https://try.crashlytics.com/).